# Metaplex - How to listen to changes of Solana Metadata URI?

Tags: solana, metaplex

Anyone knows how could I know the URI of NFT has been changed? Should I listen to new slots in SOLANA and look for the changes?

Is there a program id and type? So I can try to get the change details from instructions and inner instructions in Solana transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With @solana/web3.js you can listen for account changes in onAccountChange and then in the callback check if the URL has changed. https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange

AFAIK you only receive the new status, not the old one

Answer (score -1):

Thank @Mark Sackerberg for your supporting. How about in case we must listen from list of NFT Token (ex 1k nft tokens and still growth). I think we can't open 1k websocket connections to listen events.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should probably be a comment.

Comment: yes, I know and tried. sorry because it require at least 50 reputation for make Comment.